# how to send request from postman using multipart/form-data and read send parameter?

Tags: node.js, postman, nestjs, form-data

I am trying to send a request from postman and read the all parameters which is send in request.

here is the below request which I am trying to send through postman.

```
Fri Jan 07 Next action on [ JOB + 6129878232 ] ({"methodType":"POST","contentType":"multipart/form-data","retries":1,"params":{"CallSid":"4f958d980ff0f3e2a2352aecd79d1617","Status":"completed","RecordingUrl":"https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/exotelrecordings/ezylegal1/4f958d980ff0f3e2a2352aecd79d1617.mp3","DateUpdated":"2022-01-07 10:27:28"},"statusCallbackUrl":"https://stgbackend.ezylegal.in:4000/updateCallLogs","accountSid":"ezylegal1","srsvxJobType":"call_status_callback","jobEnqueuedTime":1641531448708,"total_retries":1,"multipart":true})
```

[image]
[image]

I am using nestjs https://nestjs.com/ framework to read request or body paramter .

but I am getting **EMPTY object**  why ?

```
  @Post('updateOneToOneCallLogs')
  async updateOneToOneCallLogs(
    @Res() res: Response,
    @Body() body
  ) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    console.log('updateOneToOneCallLogs', body);
    return res.json({name:"ddd"})
  }
```

**my logs**

```
updateOneToOneCallLogs {}
```

Comment: Where's thje `@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor())` that's necessary for `multipart/form-data`? It's what tells `multer` to parse the request